# Passing functions with varying numbers and types of parameters

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, c#-4.0

I have a lot of functions that look like this:

```
public void DoParticularThing(RecurringTaskRunResult result) {
        try {
            // Do a bunch of stuff
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            result.Succeeded = false;
            result.Results += e.ToString();
            db.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
```

So I decided to extract this out in the name of DRY code:

```
public void RunThing(Action<RecurringTaskRunResult> action, RecurringTaskRunResult result) {
        try {
            action(result);
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            result.Succeeded = false;
            result.Results += e.ToString();
            db.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
```

This way I can call `DoParticularThing` like this:

```
 RunThing(DoParticularThing, result);
```

But some of my functions also accept another parameter:

```
public void DoOtherParticularThing(RecurringTaskRunResult result, List<string> strings) {
    try {
        // Do a bunch of stuff
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        result.Succeeded = false;
        result.Results += e.ToString();
        db.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

How can I modify `RunThing` to optionally accept another parameter?

Comment: Add an overload. DRYMTYHT. Or DRY But Don't Go Overboard.

Comment: @EdPlunkett That's what I'm doing now, but it seems a step in the other direction :p

Comment: Well, you could write a method that just calls any arbitrary Action in a try/catch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps this :

```
public void RunThing(Action action, RecurringTaskRunResult result) {
    try {
        action();
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        result.Succeeded = false;
        result.Results += e.ToString();
        db.SaveChanges();
    }
}

RunThing(() => DoParticularThing(result), result);
RunThing(() => DoSomethingElse(result, list), result);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use **params** accept any parameters in your function.

```
public void RunThing(Action<RecurringTaskRunResult> action, RecurringTaskRunResult result, params object[] list) {
    try {
        action(result);
        foreach(var item in list)
        {
            // Do action with your additional parameter
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        result.Succeeded = false;
        result.Results += e.ToString();
        db.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like in all cases you want `RunThing` to have access to the `RecurringTaskRunResult` so that you can set some fields on it, but that you don't need access to any of the other parameters. You could try something like this:

```
void Action1(RecurringTaskRunResult result) { }
void Action2(RecurringTaskRunResult result, object foo) { }

RecurringTaskRunResult result = ...;
object foo = ...;
RunThing(Action1, result);
RunThing(res => Action2(res, foo), result);
```